# Cant USE databaseName against mysql using SQLDeveloper

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Yesterday I installed and ran mysql and used it to create a DB called "classicmodels".

I then connected to it using SQLDeveloper and tried to run a query to `SELECT *` from a table just to make sure things were working. When I did this it thew a "no database selected" error. The solution was to run `USE(classicmodels);`  before trying to run queries and this worked.

Today, I started SQLDeveloper back up again and tried to run a query and the same problem occured. This time, though, when trying to run the same command `USE(classicmodels);` I get this error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
USE(classicmodels)
Error at Command Line:1 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(classicmodels)' at line 1
```

My questions are:

- Why is this happening?
- How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a SQL-syntax error; use it without parentheses like:

```
USE classicmodels;
```

That would not explain why it didn't work the first time around, but I'm (politely) guessing that you used something different back then.

Comment: This results in the same error. Also it worked without parenthesis before. I copy-paisted from the .sql file I was working with yesterday.

Comment: hmm weird, I'm at a loss than sorry

Comment: I just restarted things and tried it again. This time USE classicmodels; causes a "No database selected" error to be thrown. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Even stranger. When I go from USE classicmodels to USE(classicmodels) and then back to USE classicmoodels I get the same syntax error I got for USE(classicmodels) even though I've removed the parenthesis.

Comment: A "no database selected" error after executing an USE-statement is ( or should be) impossible. After all, USE tries to do exactly that. Maybe a spelling error in "classicmodels"? If everything fails, I would opt for reinstalling MySQL (or an earlier version) and trying another GUI like HeidiSQL (free; www.heidisql.com).

Comment: I would be using HeidiSQL but I'm a MAC user (hopefully not for too much longer). It looks like there was some weirdness where SQLDeveloper was using a previous version of the file I was working in so instead of executing the USE statement it was doing something else, hence the error.